# Error in building react native app using expo

Tags: react-native, expo, lerna

I'm building fist mobile project by using react-native, expo and lerna. But I have problem with lerna. When I type: yarn install all packages. My problem is that lerna push all module packages in mobile package to the outside node_modules folder so that the script to run react native is not available in mobile package. My question is that there are any solutions for lerna to recognize those modules out of package mobile scope.

This is my folder structure

| my-project/ 
| ---- node_modules/  
| -------- react-native/ 
| -------- lerna/ 
| -------- expo/ 
| ---- package.json 
| ---- lerna.json 
| ---- packages/ 
| -------- mobile/ 
| ------------ node_modules/ 
| ---------------- bin/ 
| ------------------- react-native 
| ------------------- react-native.cmd 
| ------------ package.json